# How to match above and below lines, then insert words in between them by using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, match

How to match special characters and multiple lines at the same time? Then insert text in between those matched lines.  I would like to match lines - Sample ("xx"),direction:north and market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_b05afn10ld0b0") { as shown below. Then print text after line color code:0.000;. My coding seems wrong in somewhere. Could anyone give guidance? Thank you..

```
Sample ("apple") {
direction : north ;
      I dont want this line+: ;
      I dont want this line^ ;
      No this line : line ;
      color code: 0.000;
      I dont want this line: (c*b)+(c*a)+(b*a))" ;
      max_price : 3.6;
      min_price : 1.2;
      I dont want this line_time() {
        I dont want this line_t_sense : positive_1 ;
        No_this line either  : "c" ;
        market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_b05afn10ld0b0") {
```

My coding:

```
if(my $line =~ m/Sample(" ")/ & /direction : north/ & /market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_b05afn10ld0b0") {/ ){    #match specific line

        print "aa\n";                 #print words at previous line
}
}
```

Comment: One way is to use a multiline regexp: `s/(onelinematch)\n(secondlinematch)/$1\nnewtextinbetween\n$2/gm;`  I'm not certain about the exact flags to force a full multiline match, but that's the general idea.  Alternatively, you could loop over the individual lines and keep two consecutive lines at a time in two separate variables and write what you want to an output file when both lines match your conditions.

Comment: What does `$line` contain?

Comment: 1) You cannot chain regex matches using the bitwise AND `&` operator. For one thing, its the wrong operator. For another, you have to use the `=~` operator again for the new regex. 2) If you use `my $line`, that means you declare a new `$line` variable, which is empty. It will never match anything except the empty string, and if you had warnings turned on you would know this.

Comment: @TLP- Thanks. I would like to match line by line in this file. That is what $line means. There are a lot of similar lines like the above sample code. How to match those lines if they are not in fix words? Let's say Sample ("orange")..Sample ("adf"),  market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_j09dfia3jnhfi").. {, market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_b04jfid0000ere") { ? Only direction : output is a fix line.

Answer (score 0):

Try following `perl` one-liner from *shell*

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(Sample\s*\("[^"]+"\)\s*\{.*direction\s*:\s*\w+\s*;.*color\s*code:\s*0.000;)(.*market_fall\s*\("[^"]+"\))/$1\nLineYouWantToInsert$2/gs' file
```

**EDIT**

If you must use it within a `perl script` try following piece of code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die $!;
my $line = do { local $/; <$fh> };
$line =~ s/(Sample\s*\("[^"]+"\)\s*\{.*direction\s*:\s*\w+\s*;.*color\s*code:\s*0.000;)(.*market_fall\s*\("[^"]+"\))/$1\nLineYouWantToInsert$2/gs;
print $line;
close $fh
```

Comment: `(?:.|\n)*` better written `[.\n]*`, however you should really consider using the `/s` modifier which allows the wildcard `.` to also match newline. Which would then simplify that to `.*`.

Comment: Also, the use of backslash to denote capture groups, e.g. `\1`, is deprecated. You should use scalar variable notation, e.g. `$1`.

Comment: @TLP Thanks for your comments. Changed `\1` to `$1`. But `[.\n]*` didn't work for me. Can you please cross check? I didn't know about `/s` and will surely look at it.

Comment: It seems `.` does not retain its meta character functionality inside a character class bracket `[ ... ]`, so it cannot be used. Skip that part and just use `.*` with the `/s` modifier.

Comment: @jkshah, Thank you. Can I use one liner and perl script at the same time? Is it I need to use #!/bin/sh instead of #!/usr/bin/perl to invoke perl?

Comment: @user2943530 This one-liner needs to be invoked from shell so yes, it needs `#!/bin/sh`. If you must use it within another perl you need to expand it or use back-ticks to invoke ticks on shell from within perl

Comment: @user2943530 See **EDIT** in my ans. I've added perl script portion also.

Comment: @jkshah, thanks again. I have another question here. There are a lot of similar lines like the above sample code. How to match those lines if they are not in fix words? Let's say Sample ("orange")..Sample ("adf"), market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_j09dfia3jnhfi").. {, market_fall ("when_promotion_8X10_b04jfid0000ere") { ? Only direction : output is a fix line.

Comment: @user2943530 you can use `"[^"]+"` to match words between double quotes e.g. `"orange"`, or `\w+` to just match a single word without any spaces e.g. `north`. Updated ans with this change. Please check.

Comment: @jkshah, thank you. I tried one liner at my side but fail with this error: Can't locate autodie.pm. By using usual perl script, could you advice on how to perfectly match those lines and insert text at the right place?

Comment: @user2943530 It seems your perl installation doesn't have `autodie` module. In such case I have removed it from `perl` script code. Please check ans now.

Answer (score 0):

I like abiessu's suggestion.  Here is some sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $l1;
my $l2;

    while( my $line = <> ){
      $l1 = $l2;
      $l2 = $line;

        if( $l1 =~ /start1/ && $l2 =~ /start2/ ){
            print $l1;
            print "Inserted Text\n";
            print $l2;
      }
      else {
            print $l2;
      }
    }
```

given the input:

```
a
b
c
start1
start2
d
e
```

You will get:

```
a
b
c
start1
start1
Inserted Text
start2
d
e
```